# fail2ban-apache not blocking IP

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, fail2ban

I'm trying to configure fail2ban, I attempted to log into my web server numerous times to trigger the rule and looking at my iptables it seems to have worked:

```
Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  192.168.1.70         0.0.0.0/0
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

But if I try and access the Apache server from .70 I still can!

Any ideas?

Full list as requested:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 100998 packets, 137858737 bytes)
     pkts      bytes target        prot opt in     out     source         destination

       0        0 fail2ban-apache  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
    1925   322694 fail2ban-ssh     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0      0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source             destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 43963 packets, 7223477 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source             destination

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source             destination

       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.1.70         0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source             destination

    1925   322694 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: What do the rest of your rules look like?  Show the whole output from `iptables -L -nvx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has happened here is that after attempting to SSH in several times, the fail2ban rule has added `192.168.1.70` to the `fail2ban-apache` chain, but this chain is only followed for ports 80 and 443.  Port 22 is still allowed because `192.168.1.70` has not been added to the `fail2ban-ssh` chain.

You would find that you can't make http or https requests from your web server from `192.168.1.70` but you can still SSH.

You will probably want to change the fail2ban action for the SSH rule to block SSH rather than http and https.

Comment: Hi, I think I need to clarify some points.  I have apache hosted on a port 9000, it was that which I tried to log into and failed, triggering the rule.  SSH doesn't come into play here, i'm solely experiencing the issue with apache not blocking.

Comment: There's nothing in your iptables that references port 9000 at all, so traffic on this port will fall through to the POLICY which is ACCEPT in all cases.  With that information, it seems that the correct thing to do would be to change the `fail2ban-apache` rule to act on port 9000 rather than 80 and 443.

Comment: Ahh so obvious.  Forgive my idiocy i'm new to linux

Comment: Meh, I configured fail2ban-apache rule but it still gives me the same iptable

Chain fail2ban-apache (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  192.168.1.70         anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Comment: Again, idiocy, edited the wrong file.  working beautifully now! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the rules with higher precedence is allowing the communication before the firewall gets to your block rule. Block rules should come first, or very close to first, in your rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block all port when appear a bruteforce ssh attack or apache attack you need to add or edit this lines :

```
banaction = iptables-allports
```

after the `[ssh]` or `[apache]`  lines at  `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` or here for a default action

```
# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define
# action_* variables. Can be overridden globally or per
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-allports
```

if you don't want to block all port, you can add port name,numerical at this line

```
[apache]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https,dns,6969 <-
filter   = apache-auth
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
maxretry = 6
```